# how can i use hog/hof output as input of SS-US-ELM algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have [SS-US-ELM algorithm](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/egbhuang/elm_codes.html) Matlab codes. I want to use hog/hof on a data set like [KTH](http://www.nada.kth.se/cvap/actions/) and use its output as input of SS-ELM algorithm. but I don't know how to save the output so that the SS-ELM algorithm can get it correctly.

there is a "g50c.mat" file in the demo file that contains 4 variables ,x, y, idxLabs, idxUnls. how can I make a ".mat" file of the KTH data set and use it as input instead of "g50c.mat". any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the code for loading the "g50c.mat" and using its variables:

```js
% Semi-supervised ELM (US-ELM) for semi-supervised classification.
% Ref: Huang Gao, Song Shiji, Gupta JND, Wu Cheng, Semi-supervised and
% unsupervised extreme learning machines, IEEE Transactions on Cybernetics, 2014

format compact;
clear; 

addpath(genpath('functions'))

% load data
trial=1; 
load g50c;
l=size(idxLabs,2);
u=ceil(size(y,1)*3/4)-2*l;
Xl=X(idxLabs(trial,:),:);
Yl=y(idxLabs(trial,:),:);

% Creat validation set
labels=unique(y); 
idx_V=[];
for i=1:size(labels)
    idx_V=[idx_V;find(y(idxUnls(trial,:))==labels(i),l/length(labels),'first')];
end
Xv=X(idxUnls(trial,idx_V),:);
Yv=y(idxUnls(trial,idx_V));

% Creat unlabeled and testing set
idxSet=1:size(idxUnls,2);
idx_UT=setdiff(idxSet,idx_V);
idx_rand=randperm(size(idx_UT,2));
Xu=X(idxUnls(trial,idx_UT(idx_rand(1:u))),:);
Yu=y(idxUnls(trial,idx_UT(idx_rand(1:u))),:);
Xt=X(idxUnls(trial,idx_UT(idx_rand(u+1:end))),:);
Yt=y(idxUnls(trial,idx_UT(idx_rand(u+1:end))),:);
```